# On a new identity involving the sum of remainders function

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ the sum of divisors function, and $s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n n \operatorname{mod} k$ the sum of remainders function, then for $n\geq 2$ $$\sigma(n)+s(n)=s(n-1)+2n-1$$ holds, see for example the proof of Theorem 1, in Spivey, *The Humble Sum of Remainders Function*, Mathematics Magazine Vol. 78, No. 4, (2005). I am interested in deduce new identities involving these functions, I believe that the sum of remainders function is an interesting arithmetic function. This night I tried this, but I believe that my deductions isn't so interesting as deduced by Spivey, because mine are artificious.

My attempt was inspiring in such calculations to combine an arithmetical identity, in my case the sum of a geometric series with previous identity. In this Question, I am asking if my deductions were rights and if you can see a different approach to get more identities:

For $k\geq 1$ then a specialisation provide us $$\sigma(n^k)+s(n^k)=s(n^k-1)+2n^k-1,$$ and since $n>1$ the sum of the geometric series $$\sum_{k=1}^m n^k=\frac{n^{m+1}-n}{n-1}$$ then 
$$\sum_{k=1}^m\sigma(n^k)+\sum_{k=1}^m s(n^k)-\sum_{k=1}^m s(n^k-1)=2\frac{n^{m+1}-n}{n-1}-m.$$
And a new specialisation of this last identity, taking now $m=d$ as the divisors of $n=N$ (this last is only notation) and taking the sum for $d\mid N$ provide us **the first identity** $$\sum_{d\mid N}\sum_{k=1}^d\left(\sigma(N^k)+s(N^k)-s(N^k-1)\right)=2\frac{N}{N-1}\left(\sum_{d\mid N} N^d-\sigma_0(N)\right)-\sigma(N).$$
Here with $\sigma_0(N)=\sum_{d\mid N}1$ we are denoting the divisor-counting function. But as I was said I don't know if previous identity in LHS is interesting because is artificious (a tautology with respect RHS).

As a second approach, from our first deduction, when I multiplied by $-2$ and after I've added $-1$ then I've deduced **this second identity** 
$$-1-2\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\sigma(n^k)+s(n^k)-s(n^k-1)\right)=-4\frac{n^{m+1}-n}{n-1}+\sigma(m)+s(m)-s(m-1).$$

> **Question.** a) Are there mistakes in the **deduced identities**? b) Can you deduce a new identity using this idea?, I say with specialisation for different sequences of integers and combining with an arithmetic identity or asymptotic identities, that provide us some more interesting identity involving the sum of remainders function and the sum of divisors function.

My purpose is edit good posts in this Mathematics Stack Exchange, thus those answers for b) will be the best reference for all us in this site. **Many thanks.**

Comment: Of course if you can add a simplification or a remark about my identities in a) you are welcome. If my calculations were rights for a) only is required a *Yes* Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't your second equation be $\sigma(n^k)+s(n^k)=s(n^k-1)+2n^k-1$ ?

Comment: Yes there were typos that I've fixed in the second and third identities. I hope some answer this week, I believe that the sum of remainders function is an interesting function, the problem that my question to be more interesting is that I don't use the telescoping trick, thus I don't know if it's possible to do good mathematics as Spivey did. Many thanks for your attention @MatthewConroy

Comment: I don't find the sum of remainders function to be interesting, since $s(n)+\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma(j) =n^2$, so it doesn't seem that $s(n)$ adds much (despite what Spivey's paper says).  But maybe other people will be interested in checking out your identities. Cheers!

Comment: It was myself opinion, that is interesting. Well we know a lot of about the sum of divisors, but not about the sum of remainders (these kind of things are interestings to me). Any case, for the mean that you are saying $\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma(j)$ we know Bachmann's theorem, but the behaviour of an item $\sigma(n)$ of such identity also is a mistery and erratic: since we have an open question concerning the growth of $\sigma(n)$ for $n>5040$, that is the Riemann's Hypothesis (see Robin or Lagarias statement), and since we know $n^2$ exactly, I am interested in $s(n)$. Many thanks @MatthewConroy